# retrieving data attribute from one to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a one to many relationship as defiened below

```
public function property() {
    return $this->hasOne(Property::class);
}
```

and

```
public function propertycalendars(){
    return $this->hasMany(PropertyCalendar::class,'property_id');
}
```

and here in my controller i get the relation like this :

```
 $property = Property::with('propertycalendars')->get();
   return view('users.properties.show',compact('property'));
```

but in view if i try to get title of property it says

```
Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance
```

i wana get the title and the relation attribute that i defined and here is the dd of my $propery which shows the data is there but i just dont know how to access it by the way its the show method of laravel

```
Collection {#1297 ▼


 #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Property {#1245 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "properties"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:12 [▶]
      #original: array:12 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "propertycalendars" => Collection {#1296 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => PropertyCalendar {#1291 ▼
              #connection: "mysql"
              #table: "property_calendars"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:6 [▶]
              #original: array:6 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: []
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #fillable: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
$property = Property::with('propertycalendars')->get();
```

doesn't fetch one property, it fetches *all* your properties into a collection. Each of those properties has a title.

You'd typically `@foreach` through these in the view:

```
@foreach($property as $prop)
    {{ $prop->title }}
@endforeach
```

(I'd rename `$property` to `$properties` for clarity, incidentally.)

Comment: thats fine i got them but how can i access the relationship here ??

Comment: Each property's will be in `$prop->propertycalendars`. Since it's a `hasMany`, you'll have to `foreach` through those, as well. So if you're showing a list of all properties and all their calendars, you'll have two nested foreaches.

Comment: aa ok so can i ask you please to guide me how can i fetch only 1 property as i said its a show method of my laravel consider this link http://localhost:8000/properties/1 i am here now so i am showing 1 property or is it even possible to do this with has many

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent's bit about "Retrieving Single Models".

Comment: Also check Laravel's route parameters: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters